# android - Broadcast of Intent Has extras error

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, android-anr-dialog

I have a broadcast receiver that detects when a USB device is attached/detached. The app opens when the device is connected however when i disconnect/connect the device to my android multiple times, i get the following ANR error:  Does anyone know what is causing this?
[ANR error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd3iv.png)

Here is my Broadcast Receiver code:

```
    String USB_TAG = "USB_TAG";
    String BROADCAST_TAG = "BROADCAST_TAG";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(BROADCAST_TAG, "BroadcastReceiver Event");
        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d(BROADCAST_TAG, "BroadcastReceiver DEVICE ATTACHED");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Device Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    if(MainActivity.eMRO_Backend != null) {
                        if (MainActivity.eMRO_Backend.threadsClosed) {
                            MainActivity.eMRO_Backend = new eMRO_Backend(context);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d(BROADCAST_TAG, "BroadcastReceiver attach ex: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }).start();
        } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {  
            Toast.makeText(context, "Device Not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new Thread(() -> {
                Looper.prepare();
                try {
                    MainActivity.powerStatusQueue.put(false);
                    MainActivity.laserKeyStatusQueue.put(false);
                    if(MainActivity.eMRO_Backend != null)
                        MainActivity.eMRO_Backend.shutDownThreads();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(BROADCAST_TAG, "BroadcastReceiver detach ex: " + e.getMessage());
                }

            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That `Looper.prepare()` seems scary.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. The ANR indicates that `onReceive()` is running for too long. your code doesn't look like it should run for long at all. Add some logging to see the entry and exit from `onReceive()`. Also, this is bad practice. You should not start threads in a broadcast receiver. You should start a Service instead.

Comment: @CommonsWare OP is calling `Looper.prepare()` inside a new `Thread`. Generally speaking, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @DavidWasser I also tried using an AsyncTask , but got the same error. When I get the ANR, i dont see any of the log statement in my onReceive method.

Comment: OK, that probably means that your broadcast receiver **is not** the problem. The problem is that you've got code running on your main (UI) thread that is blocking the main(UI) thread. When Android tries to call your broadcast receiver's `onReceive()`, the call is blocked by something else and that is what is causing the ANR. What you are seeing is a **symptom** and not the actual **cause** of the problem.

Comment: @DavidWasser you were right, it was a function on my main activity causing this issue. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad you were able to solve the issue. I created an answer. You can accept the answer if it was helpful and that will remove this question from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your broadcast receiver is not the problem. The problem is that you've got code running on your main (UI) thread that is blocking the main (UI) thread. When Android tries to call your broadcast receiver's `onReceive()`, the call is blocked by something else and that is what is causing the ANR. What you are seeing is a **symptom** and not the actual **cause of the problem**.